# Create a table with for loop (R)

Tags: r

I am new at using R software and I need your help.

I have many variables (columns) in this data and I need to present them in one table using for loop. I used this code but only one variable is saved in the table.

Could anyone please amend the code?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
#install.packages('arsenal')
library(arsenal)
data(gapminder)

for (i in 4:6)
{table_one <- tableby(continent ~ gapminder[[i]], 
                     data = gapminder)
summary(table_one, title = "Gapminder Data", text=TRUE)


write2word(table_one, "table 1.doc",
           keep.md = TRUE,
           quiet = TRUE,
           
           title = "Maximum ROM of the main movements")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the file name is the same `"table 1.doc"`, thus overwriting the table already produced in each of the iteration.  The output we get after running the loop is from the last iteration

```
for (i in 4:6){
  table_one <- tableby(continent ~ gapminder[[i]], 
                     data = gapminder)
   print(summary(table_one, title = "Gapminder Data", text=TRUE))

   filename <- paste0("table", i, ".doc")
   write2word(table_one, filename,
           keep.md = TRUE,
           quiet = TRUE,
           
           title = "Maximum ROM of the main movements")

}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make all the variables in just one table, not separate?

Comment: @alawipt You could rbind the output to a list and use `write2word` outside the `for` loop or if there is an `append`, use `append = TRUE`